# Can any one help me out how to decrypt(AES128) the message in iOS which is encrypted in JAVA (AES Decryption 128)

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

Please find the below method which we are using.

The key received from server in Hexa: 1EF5F2D644FBA8E4142778CD43D70BFA

The encoded message received from server: /lGtPU2K29FZPNtrc9DKow==

If we decrypt the above message it should be "hi"

I am unable to decrypt it in iOS side. Can anyone help me out please.

```
- (NSData *)AES128DecryptWithKey:(NSString *)key 
{
    // 'key' should be 16 bytes for AES128, will be null-padded otherwise
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or 
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesDecrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, 0,keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES128,
                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesDecrypted);

    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess)
    {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesDecrypted];
    }

    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Can you add java code that encrypt text?

Comment: @rayyildiz: Please find the java code below.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, 
                                      kCCAlgorithmAES128, 
                                      kCCOptionECBMode | kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                      keyPtr, 
                                      kCCKeySizeAES128,
                                      NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                      [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                      buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                      &numBytesDecrypted);
```

Comment: I tried with the code you provided, but it is not returning any data. But the code which i am previously using returns the Data. But while converting the data into string. I am getting empty string.                                                      NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:decodedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: hi sudhir, have you solved this issue because I am aslo facing same issue which you mentioned above. Please provide me the code snippet if you have solved this issue. Thanks in advance.